# Как сделать переход от одной страницы Razor к другой с помощью кнопки, которая находится на первой странице?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

Как сделать переход от одной страницы Razor к другой с помощью кнопки, которая находится на первой странице? Можете, пожалуйста, подкинуть примеры кода?

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам ответ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142422/rendering-partial-view-on-button-click-in-asp-net-mvc)

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" />

var url = '@Url.Action("DisplaySearchResults", "Search")';
$('form').submit(function() {
  if (!$(this).valid()) { 
    return false; // возврат если не прошла валидация
  }
  var form = $(this).serialize();
  $('#searchResults').load(url, form);
  return false; 
})


public ActionResult DisplaySearchResults(SearchCriterionModel criteria)
{
  var model = // создаем модель на основе входных параметров
  return PartialView("SearchResults", model);
}
```